# PhpStorm: ignore library files unless in a Test Sources Root dir

Tags: phpunit, phpstorm

Since I've begun using PHPUnit, PhpStorm 2017 has indexed `phpunit.phar` to provide code completion on my tests and that's great. Problem is, when I am not writing tests, the autocomplete suggestions are polluted with classes I never use.

In the image below, I want to throw a native `Exception` but the vast majority of suggestions are not from native code, but from `phpunit.phar`

[image]

This hurts my productivity. Is there a way to have scoped ignore rules in PhpStorm? Specifically, to ignore `phpunit.phar` classes unless I'm in its folder or a subfolder? Or even better, ignore unless I'm within a [Test Sources Root](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/directories.html) folder?

Comment: It's not possible at the moment but sounds valid to me. Could you please file a feature request? https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WI I'll take a look how it can be implemented.

Comment: @artspb Not sure how to file a feature request. I filed an issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-37635

Comment: You did it right, thanks.

Comment: What if your production code depends on `phpunit/phpunit`, for example, because it is a library intended for use with it?